# Imagick: Return position and size of circular objects in image

Tags: image, image-processing, object-detection, imagick, connected-components

I have this image:
[image: Arch]

Using this Imagick cli command:

```
magick model.png -canny 0x0+1%+10% -negate -blur 3x.7 -solarize 50% -level 50%,0 model_canny.png
```

it got converted to this :
[image: converted]

is it possible to get the position/size of the teeth in the arch? it doesn't have to be perfect. Even if it detects few teeth in the arch it would be a great for me to understand how this works. So far I've tried to use `connected-components` param and it gives me thousands of results which is obviously incorrect. Here's what I've done so far:

```
magick model_canny.png -fuzz 5% -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components 4 objects.png
```

Also is it possible to remove the random black lines inside the teeth? Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to separate objects is to use a morphological erosion, using a command something like this:

```
magick fangs.png -alpha extract -trim -morphology erode disk:5 result.png
```

Here is an animation of the effect of various disk sizes:

[image]

Taking that a bit further, you could maybe erode in a loop and then do a *"Connected Component Analysis"* and count the blobs, and keep increasing the disk size till you get a sensible number of teeth.

Or, you may need to work a bit harder and try to fit a parabola (shown in blue) to the pixels that make up the teeth if that is the best shape - not a dentist, myself! Then, with a parabola, you could find the normals to the parabola (shown in red) all the way around and take the normal that crosses the smallest amount of tooth as the boundary between the teeth. Rough diagram:

[image]

Or maybe superimpose your Canny edge-detected image on the fitted parabola, and see where your edges intersect with it.